# hd1 cannot get C/H/S values

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

Ok, I know there are many questions about this topic, but I can't found a convince answer (fixing the problem or not).

Recently I bought an SSD drive and installed in main SATA (hd0), I've replaced my cd/dvd drive with old hdd drive, using a caddy adapter.

Now I've installed Ubuntu on SSD and windows 10 on hdd.

The problem is on the boot, when I select windows in grub menu I'm faced with this error: **cannot get C/H/S values.**

I can't set hdd boot on BIOS because it's expected a ODD driver.

I have a Dell Inspiron 14R-5437.

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Are you running BIOS version A09? Have you considered contacting Dell Support about the problem you are having with the BIOS?

Answer (score 0):

Same configuration here and same error got.

My workaround was booting from the HDD instead of the SSD.
In my case, I can select the booting device on every computer start-up pressing F11 (so, I just select the HDD when I want to boot Windows).
Otherwise, you might change the boot order on the BIOS setup depending on which system you want to boot up.

Comment: But my BIOS doesn't allow me to boot from HDD, since it's on the place of the DVD, the message I get is that cannot boot from hdd since is expected an ODD driver.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried this, and enter bios and set to legacy boot, and then from boot enter command line, and enter this:

```
test hd1
badram hd1
dump hd1
```

and then use

```
set secondary=hd1
```

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: I've not tried this yet, can't test right now, by the time I test I tell you. Thanks!